# What is the name of the 144x144 app icon for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, retina-display

I am making an iPhone game. I have all the required app sizes except the one for the Retina iPad. I figured the size of the icon for that needs to be 144x144. But I don't know what to name it!

I tried Icon-144.png(similar to Icon-72.png) but when I run my app on the Retina iPad, it seems to use the Default.png image as an Icon. Very wierd!

Can any of you tell me what the name of the icon needs to be for the 144x144.

Thankssss

Comment: My fault — didn't notice your question was about the iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name it Icon@2x.png. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009882)

You could also try "Icon-iPad@2x.png". [Source](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/03/17/hi-res-app-icons-ipad-3)

Comment: Yup. I tried that too. I can't seem to find any documentation on the names for these on the apple developers website either...

Comment: It clearly states [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) you should just use @2x suffix for retina icon. If that doesn't work either just drag it into summary tab of your target.

Answer (score 2):

If:

```
Icon@2x.png
```

is not the name you're looking for, try looking at this thread over on MacRumors about [updating your graphics for the new retina iPad](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1335403).

I'd suggest trying:

```
Icon-72@2x.png
```

Here is the syntax for high resolution icon name lookup:

```
<ImageName>@2x<device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
```

Comment: Mine is an iPhone only app. But I need to know what the icon size and name should be for displaying it on Retina iPad.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Icon-72@2x.png for 144X144 ipad retina. very bad documentation apple ios have always missing things and confusing concepts.Name should be mentioned in documentation